# How to dynamically render HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Recently I came across a question, here it goes, I have two buttons `BTN1`, `BTN2`. On click of `BTN1` it should disappear and two new `BTN_A` and `BTN_B` has to appear, on click or `BTN_A`, it should disappear & `BTN1.A`, `BTN1.B` should appear. How to achieve this if I still want to click on BTN's and make them disappear.

I thought we can make "display: none" but for how many, how to render a [html](/questions/tagged/html) dynamically in the best way?

Comment: theres many libraries/frameworks that do this.

Comment: I think some JS could do the job

Comment: Learn JavaScript DOM manipulation and/or jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 possibilities to hide a DOM element like a button.
The first three are css style changes:

- opacity: 0;
- visibility: hidden;
- display: none;
- removing the element from the DOM with `removeChild()`

The needed code is the following:

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').style.opacity = '0';
document.getElementById('myBtn').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('myBtn').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

The code for adding and removing elements goes like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('endlessBtnContainer');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<button id="addBtn" onclick="addBtn()">addBtn</button>';
```

and removing

```
var div = document.getElementById('addBtn');
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

- `opacity: 0;` will simply make the element not visible, but it is still existing normally. So you can still click the button.
- `visibility: hidden;` Will hide the element, but it will still take
  up the same space it had when it was still visible. It won't be
  clickable anymore.
- `display: none;` Will hide the element and it won't take any space
  anymore. Therefore following HTML elements will flow into the new
  available space.

```css
#btnA, #btnB, #btn1A, #btn1B{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script> 
function hideElem()
{
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
   //document.getElementById(''+arguments[i]).style.opacity = '0';//just invisible, still clickable
   //document.getElementById(''+arguments[i]).style.display = "none";//no space taken
   document.getElementById(''+arguments[i]).style.visibility = "hidden";//invisible, not clickable
 } 
}

function showElem(targetElem)
{
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(''+arguments[i]).style.opacity = '1';
 } 
}

function addBtn()
{
 var div = document.getElementById('endlessBtnContainer');
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<button id="addBtn" onclick="addBtn()">addBtn</button>';
}

function removeBtn()
{
 var div = document.getElementById('addBtn');
 div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
</script>

<button id="btn1" onclick="hideElem('btn1', 'btn2'); showElem('btnA', 'btnB');">
 btn1
</button>
<button id="btn2">
 btn2
</button>

<button id="btnA" onclick="hideElem('btnA', 'btnB'); showElem('btn1A', 'btn1B');">
 btnA
</button>
<button id="btnB"> 
 btnB
</button>

<button id="btn1A">
 btn1A
</button>
<button id="btn1B">
 btn1B
</button>

<button id="addBtn" onclick="addBtn()">
 addBtn
</button>
<button id="removeBtn" onclick="removeBtn()">
 removeBtn
</button>
<div id="endlessBtnContainer"> 
</div>
```